# Change Initial Zoom MapKit Swift

Tags: swift

I'm new in Swift, and I'm trying to use MkMapView. I'd like to change the initial zoom. I searched On the API but I don't find anything.

I find only this, about zoom

```
mapView.zoomEnabled = true
```

But it isn't what I looking For.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MKMaps don't have a concept of zoom as a configurable variable. Zoom enabled pertains to user interaction. You'll need to configure something manually by setting a region that encompasses your desired zoom level.

For instance, if I wanted to zoom in on some specific coordinate, I could do:

```
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = // .. populate your center
let latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance = 50
let longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance = 50
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, latitudinalMeters, longitudinalMeters)
self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false) // Set to yes to animate, you said initial load so I image this won't be visible anyways.
```

Then, adjust the latitudinal/longitudinal dimensions to meet your desired zoom level.

If you wanted, you could probably create a category that adds zoom and calls this in the background.

Comment: thanks a lot!! How Could I find it in Documentation? In My opinion it isn't clear

Comment: I am not sure, it's been a while since I've looked at the documentation for MapKit.  There's probably a map programming guide that has some additional information, but I agree, this could be better documented considering it's a fairly common question.  Best of luck!

Comment: If I change latitudinalMeters and longitudinalMeters The zoom is the same

Comment: How much are you changing them by, are you sure it's just not noticeable? There also might be a max, try say 1000 meters, then 50. Still the same zoom?

Answer (score 0):

From Logan's answer, update for Swift 5+

```
let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = // .. populate your center
let latitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance = 50
let longitudinalMeters: CLLocationDistance = 50
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: latitudinalMeters, longitudinalMeters: longitudinalMeters)
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false) // Set to yes to animate, you said initial load so I image this won't be visible anyways.
```